# You have an error in your SQL syntax mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

query:

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `vip_overrides` SET `user_id` = " . $max . ", `server_id` = " . $user['server_id'] . ", `group` = '" . $user['access'] . "', `expires` = " . $user['utime'] . ", `date_create` = " . $user['time'] . "; ";
```

answer:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>       near 'INSERT INTO `vip_overrides` SET `user_id` = 1, `server_id` = 2,
>       `group` = 'vip',' at line 1

mysqli_query dont work with multy query in one string
use mysqli_multi_query

Comment: You are inserting or updating?

Comment: insert http://f6.s.qip.ru/cMfvWwUs.png

Comment: you shouldn't be using this MAX() thing. Use auto increment instead.

Comment: sql query in while? rly?

Comment: In order to find the error you should send the full SQL statement which has been send to the databese not only the PHP part and the error message. Make a echo of `$sql` and post it please.

Comment: if i copy echo of $sql and paste in phpmyadmin its work..

Comment: i think error in ";"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run multiple queries using mysqli_query.

If it's different queries, then run them separately, one by one.

If it's the same query but with different data, use a prepared statement.

Comment: Although I cannot extract any useful information from your laconic remarks, but I have a feeling that you need to pay more attention to the answers given.

Comment: You say you "know it" but your code says different. Afaics, this is _the_ answer.

Comment: answer on this problem in my first post

Comment: @JonStirling: one query is better than multiple queries, though. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In this case, sure ;)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: huh? I meant that using `INSERT ... VALUES` is the better way here.

Answer (score 1):

@YourCommonSense is right, you can't run multiple commands in the same call to `mysqli_query`. However, you can reorganize your string building to produce just one command.

You have this as your resulting `$sql` value:

```
INSERT INTO foo SET a = 1, b = 2; 
INSERT INTO foo SET a = 3, b = 4;
```

Change your code to make it produce this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4);
```